# When I'm in VI command mode my H and L keys do not work

Tags: command

I am new to using VI. I'm using a virtual machine. When I'm in command mode and pressing <kbd>l</kbd> it used to take me to the right and <kbd>h</kbd> used to take me to the left.

Now when I am in command mode pressing <kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>l</kbd> will take me to the first character on the first line. I'm sure I'm in command mode because I press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key after being in insert mode.

All the other keys work as expected.

Comment: I think you mean "Normal" mode ("Command" mode is when you're typing a command after `:`.) Are you sure you don't have Caps Lock on? If you use `H` instead of `h`, that will make the cursor move to the top line on the screen...

Comment: @filbranden normal mode did used to be called command mode; the : is the command-line, I think, to distinguish. I see command mode particularly from traditional vi users

Comment: Possibly helpful [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)
[How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604)