# Vim shortcut for :tabprevious change opened file on start

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, navigation

I try to configure my `.vimrc` file adding new shortcuts for my daily routing.

One of my basic operations in every single IDE is switching between "tabs". I suppose to put the same key binding for each IDE i'm using on actually and ViM also suitable for me (sometimes).

The next code (`.vimrc`) works perfectly with any existed file I've opened in Vim.

```
" Create / Navigate through Tabs
nnoremap <C-t> :tabnew<CR>
nnoremap <C-]> :tabnext<CR>

inoremap <C-t> <Esc>:tabnew<CR>
inoremap <C-]> <Esc>:tabnext<CR>i
```

Here's just 2 commands: create new tab and move to next.
But I want to move **back** as well!

Next code

```
nnoremap <C-[> :tabprevious<CR>
inoremap <C-[> <Esc>:tabprevious<CR>i
```

provides strange behaviour for opened files (existed only).

[image: my vimrc screenshort]

**The Questions**

How can I fix such shortcut code and make it correct for ViM?

Comment: Are you aware that entering `Ctrl-[` is the same as pressing  `Esc`? In insert mode type `Ctrl-V` then one of them then `Ctrl-V` and the other. Same output.

Comment: No, I don't. Is there an option how to re-bind `Ctrl-[` to my needs? @BLayer

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I'm fairly sure we have a duplicate question about mapping `<C-[>` breaking because it duplicates `<Esc>`. But anyway for this kind of questions [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841) can be useful, the part about `Remember that some key combinations are equivalent` especially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapping the escape key like this tends to break things because of the way certain special characters are handled (references needed/appreciated). I would also recommend avoiding `<C-t>` and `<C-]>` as they are pretty useful commands (`:help CTRL-T`, `:help CTRL-]`). You might want to know about `gt` and `gT` for navigating tabs. They also take a count.

---

Here's some recommended reading on tabs. Use them however you want, of course! These helped inform my workflow, though:

- [buffers, windows, tabs](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/buffers-windows-tabs/)
- [vim buffers over tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs)
- [vim tab madness](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/)