# Jumping to open paren with % doesn't work when open paren followed by $ and cursor is in method call experssion

Tags: delimiter-matching

Neovim .6.1

Got this line:

`add_post_meta($this->cmr_id, 'intro_paragraph', 'Hello');`

With:

```
add_post_meta($this->cmr_id, 'intro_paragraph', 'Hello');
                                 ^ cursor here
```

Hitting '%' key jumps to opening paren as expected.

But with:

```
add_post_meta($this->cmr_id, 'intro_paragraph', 'Hello');
                 ^ cursor here
```

Nothing happens. <del>If I remove the $, it works.</del>

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with nvim 0.6.1 you probably want to check [how do I debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841) or maybe check if you have a mapping on `%` which causes an issue ([How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)). EDIT: Or it is a filetype issue. It would be worth checking that the issue still happens after using `set ft=` or if it happens with different filetypes.

Comment: Ok I actually can reproduce in both vim and nvim if I set the filetype to `php`. That looks like a bug in the matchit plugin when using php... Maybe it would be worth creating an issue on Github. Also [@ChristianBrabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) is listed as the maintainer of matchit in the source code, maybe he is the right person to ask this question to.

Comment: OK, yeah, I was just about to come here and report I think it's a filetype issue. Thanks!

Comment: So, turns out the php.vim script in vim calls html.vim script. html.vim script is the culprit. If I comment out the line that loads it, things works as expected.

Comment: I didn't check the repo's issues but it could be worth creating one so that maintainers can fix it.

Comment: I added an issue to neovim. They closed and it and told me to submit issue to vim. I have a better workaround below.

Comment: Yeah I think neovim gets the matchit plugin from the vim repo so it makes sense they ask you to create it there. Your second solution is nice

Comment: You don't want to know how long it took to figure that out. Vim is like one big giant hack on a hack.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a much better fix, albeit probably not perfect.

In `after/ftplugin/php.vim`, add the following 3 lines:

```
let b:match_words .= '<?php:[^-]>'
set matchpairs-=<:>
let b:match_words = substitute(b:match_words, '<:>', '<:\@<=[^-]>', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a bug in html.vim which gets loaded by php.vim.

Hack fix:

Comment out:

`"setlocal matchpairs+=<:>`

And:

```
"if exists("loaded_matchit")
"    let b:match_ignorecase = 1
"    let b:match_words = '<:>,' .
"    \ '<\@<=[ou]l\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=li\>:<\@<=/[ou]l>,' .
"    \ '<\@<=dl\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=d[td]\>:<\@<=/dl>,' .
"    \ '<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
"endif
```