# a `nnoremap <buffer><silent>` on .vimrc make the curssor very slow on normal mode

Tags: vimrc, normal-mode, performance, vim8

To automate a bit the title creation for rst text I added this to my `.vimrc`:

```
au FileType rst nnoremap <buffer><silent>h1 yypVr=o                                                 
au FileType rst nnoremap <buffer><silent>h2 yypVr-o                                                 
au FileType rst nnoremap <buffer><silent>h3 yypVr~o                                                 
au FileType rst nnoremap <buffer><silent>h4 yypVr`o
```

So on a `test.rst` file with the cursor on any line like this:

```
This should be a |title

some text
```

`h1` produce this:

```
This should be a title
======================
|
some text
```

It work very well well but ...

it make the cursor move very very slow, each time I press `b` to go backward it take **1 second** !

Comment: I believe you have a keybinding that starts with b. You should try ``:verbose map b``. Then vim wait for the next key to decide if it is a b or a keybinding

Comment: The mappings do seem unrelated (I recommending using ftplugins for them instead of autocommands, though). Check out [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604)
 to see if there's something else causing the problem