# How can I get netrw to not move the cursor when I return to it

Tags: netrw, cursor

When I open a directory in netrw by opening vim like `vim .`, it will show me a list of files in the current directory. If I find a file then press `t` it will open that file in a new tab, when I'm done, I'll close the file with `:q`, then the netrw tab will be shown again but my cursor will be at the top, not over the file I just opened. How do I get it to not move the cursor?

Comment: Following your description, my cursor stays on the same file

Comment: Have a look at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) and 
[How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604) to make sure nothing is interfering

Comment: What version of vim/netrw are you on? I'm on 8.2/168. and I removed my .vim/.vimrc away and it still happens.

Comment: Personally with `8.2.4699` (netrw dates to 9th Feb 2021 according to header) I don't have the issue you describe; instead, the cursor stays on the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the following line in my .vimrc:

```
let g:netrw_fastbrowse = 2
```

When that variable is set to 2, it will not refresh the listing every time you enter the buffer, and so it will not position your cursor at the top of the screen.

Extra info:

I found within netrw there's an autocommand like this:

```
au BufEnter *  sil call s:LocalBrowse(expand("<amatch>"))
```

not sure what it's trying to do, but if I disable it, makes my cursor stay where I want it to be. So I wrote a file in ~/.vim/after/plugin/netrw.vim with this line:

```
au! FileExplorer BufEnter
```

while this works with starting vim like `vim .` it doesn't work when running something like `:e .` once inside vim. So the better solution is to set the variable above.