# Why is this mapping deleting text?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'm using these two binding for indentation and dedentation of a visual selected block of text.

```
" Indentation
vmap <TAB>  >gv

" Dedentation
vmap <S-TAB>    <gv
```

When I dedent with my binding everything is fine, but if I try to indent with `<Tab>` the text gets deleted. I am not using any plugins and this is my `vimrc`:

```
"-----------------------------------------------
" my .VIMRC, the root                           |
"-----------------------------------------------
" only if not set before:
" use vim-defaults instead
" of vi-defaults (easier, more user friendly)
if &compatible          
  set nocompatible      
endif

syntax on
set relativenumber  " hybrid
set number      " hybrid
set mouse=a

set shell=/bin/bash 

"case-insensitive searching
set ignorecase      
set smartcase

" Disable audible/visual bells
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=

" setting formating stuff
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set autoindent

"show matching pairs -> () [] {}
set showmatch

" copy to clipboard
noremap <C-y> "+y  

" paste from clipboard
noremap <C-p> "+p  

" Indentation
vmap <TAB>  >gv

" Dedentation
vmap <S-TAB>    <gv
```

The version I'm using is `VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0` . Does anyone have the same problem or have an idea where the root of this problem is?

Comment: Try `xnoremap`—`vmap` is probably not what you want. cf. [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604), [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604)

Comment: I have tested on Vim and gVim 9.00 on Windows and it seems to work fine for me :-|. Maybe should you give us more indication. What is the text that you select. What is the result after hitting tab in Visual mode.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It occured at any kind of text. When I hit tab, I'm tabbing in deleting the selected text and going in insert-mode.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem with the three type of Visual mode (Visual, Visual-Block, Visual-Line) it works fine on my Windows box with Vim 9.00 and on my Ubuntu box with Vim 8.2. Maybe could you try to start vim without `.vimrc`: `vim -u NONE -i NONE` enter the map command in the vim command mode `:` and try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The answer explains why @VivianDeSmedt couldn't reproduce: likely the RHS of the mapping triggered another mapping that they didn't have (or that `vim -u NONE -i NONE` doesn't have).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `vmap` which is recursivly and works in `select`- and `visual`-mode, I switched to `xnoremap` which isn't recursivly and restricts to only visual mode. Now it works fine!