# toggleterm.nvim - how to set keymap for ToggleTermSendVisualLines

Tags: neovim

I am struggling to find a working keymap for ToggleTermSendVisualLines - every time I try for example `<Leader>cl`, it jumps to insert mode (also deleting the visual selection). The same happens with starting the keymap with `s`. Could you please suggest a working keymap and let me know why these fail to work?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Try [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604), and note that if you don't have visual mode mappings on `<leader>cl` or `s`, it's probable you're getting `v_c` or `v_s` behavior, which is to delete the visual selection and start Insert mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem was that I copied from another map that was for normal mode, not visual.