# Coc Nvim automatically select all text between tags

Tags: vimrc, plugin-coc

I have mapped esc to < C-J> in .vimrc and whenever I try to go to normal mode after inserting some text inside any html tag using that mapping it selects all the character between that tag like this: [image]

and remove all the character to what I type after that like I wanna navigate to up or down using j and k it insert those characters only.
Help me to solve this problem.

**NOTE: This happens to only jsx file and not normal html file.**

**Update:** The Image above is in Select mode that means after pressing those mappings it changes to select mode and select those things between them but nothing is mapped to < C-J> (except esc) in my :map list.

These are the mappings in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F5> :!g++-12 -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover -DLOCAL -g % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>
nnoremap <C-F5> :!clang++-14 -std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover -DLOCAL  -g % -o %:r && ./%:r<CR>
noremap <C-T> :tabnew <CR>
noremap <C-E> :Explore <CR>
noremap <C-A> ggVG
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<C-o>O
vnoremap <C-C> :w !xclip -i -sel c <CR>
inoremap <C-J> <ESC>
vnoremap <C-J> <ESC>
```

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604), [How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604). Please share the exact mapping and steps starting from `vim --clean` that reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suspect that one of your plugin has an influence. As suggested by @Ben, could you reproduce the problem when you start Vim with the `--clean` flag (`vim --clean`). It start vim, load your `.vimrc` but don't load the plugins.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned already it is due to (Coc Nvim) plugin it doesn't happen when I use vim --clean because autocomplete (provided by same plugin) don't work there.