# How to map a number followed by another key?

Tags: key-bindings

[I have read [How to debug a mapping?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7723) and although that is a great starting point I am still clueless why this does not work.]

I want `2*` to search for the next occurence of the previous word in combination with the current word.

I have defined it in my vimrc in the following way:

```
nnoremap 2* hevgeb"zy/\<<C-R>z\><CR>
```

but pressing 2* ignores this mapping and searches for the 2nd occurence of the current word.

`:map 2*` shows that the keys are mapped correctly:

```
n  2*          * hevgeb"zy/\<<C-R>z\><CR>
```

Pressing `o2*` inserts `2*` on a new line and thereby proves that the keys are not intercepted, vim receives the keys as expected.

Leaving out the 2 remaps asterisk as expected and shows that `hevgeb"zy/\<<C-R>z\><CR>` does what it's intended to do. I am not happy with this implementation because it changes a register (z) but surprisingly I have not found an easy way to avoid that.

In a different mapping 2 followed by tab to show a table of contents works some times and some times not, but pressing it several times eventually triggers it:

```
nnoremap 2<Tab> :exec '!grep --color=always --line-number -E "^[[:space:]]*((class\|def) +([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\|\# (===\|---).*)"' shellescape(@%, 1) " \| less -R"<cr>
```

Based on that experience I have tried pressing `2*` and here, too, it works in some cases. But what's annoying for the 2tab mapping is not acceptable for the 2* mapping because it moves the cursor.

Does somebody know in which circumstances these mappings work and in which not and how to trigger them reliably? I thought that pressing escape before might help but it does not. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `*` that you need to map, not `2*`:

```
nnoremap <expr> * v:count1 == 2 ? 'hevgeb"zy/\<<C-R>z\><CR>' : '*'
```

- This is an "expression mapping", where the RHS is the result of an expression evaluated at runtime. See `:help map-<expr>`.
- If `:help v:count1` equals 2, then do your custom magic.
- If not, just do `[count]*`.

So, basically…

| What you press | What you get |
| --- | --- |
| `*` | `*` |
| `1*` | `1*` |
| `2*` | `hevgeb"zy/\<<C-R>z\><CR>` |
| `3*` | `3*` |
| `4*` | `4*` |
| `5*` | `5*` |
| etc. | etc. |

That said, your mapping works as-is, here, so you should probably do some digging on your side, starting with `$ vim --clean` and `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: I needed to add an `<esc>` in front of the `h` so that the 2 does not affect it