# # key causing delay in Neovim

Tags: neovim, key-bindings

Whenever I input `#` in Neovim I get delay. I tried to fix this with

```
nnoremap # <nop>
vnoremap # <nop>
```

In my `init.vim` but that seemed to only fix it in non `.tex` environments. I assume this has something to do with the plugins I am using. Specifically, I suspect this is an issue with `vimtex` / `ultisnips`.

**Question:** Can someone help me diagnose where this is comming from and to disable it?

**Extra:** To `:verbose imap #`

I am getting

```
i  #B          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#B", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathbb")
)
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/
imaps.vim line 119
i  #-          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#-", vimtex#imaps#style_math("overline
"))
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/
imaps.vim line 119
i  #c          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#c", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathcal"
))
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/
imaps.vim line 119
i  #f          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#f", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathfrak
"))
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/
imaps.vim line 119
i  #b          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#b", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathbf")
)
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/
imaps.vim line 119
i  #/          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#/", vimtex#imaps#style_math("slashed"
))
        Last set from ~/.config/nvim/pack/plugins/start/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/
imaps.vim line 119
```

Comment: Do you have the delay in normal mode or in input mode?

Comment: Hi. The input is in input mode. For example when I type #, nvim displays it with the cursor like |#  waits one second and becomes #|

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604),
[How to debug a mapping](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/10604)

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise may be could you accept one solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the quesrion to rest :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that you have a mapping or several mapping that starts with `#` and that Vim is waiting you type another key to solve the ambiguity.

To know more about the mapping that starts with `#` you can use:

```
:verbose nmap #
```

If the problem you have is input mode you can use:

```
:verbose imap #
```

VimTex comes with several mapping in insert mode that starts with `#`

- `#B`
- `#b`
- `#c`
- `#f`
- `#-`
- `#/`

More information about the insert mode mapping that comes with `vimtex` with `:help vimtex-imaps`.

You can list all the `vimtex` insert mode mapping with:

```
:VimtexImapsList
```

Unless you deactivate all of them when you hit `#` you have to type an additional character such that Vim knows what to do.

You can disable these mapping by setting the following variable into your `init.vim` file:

```
let g:vimtex_imaps_disabled = ['b', 'B', 'c', 'f', '/', '-']
```

That should solve your problem.

But if you fail to prevent them to be created you can delete them by adding a `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` with the following content:

`~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
iunmap <buffer> #B
iunmap <buffer> #b
iunmap <buffer> #c
iunmap <buffer> #f
iunmap <buffer> #-
iunmap <buffer> #/
```

Comment: Hi I am afraid this doesn't work. I have added an additional comment bellow my question. I can also provide a gif if nothing comes to mind as to what could be causing it.

Comment: Could you provide the result of the command proposed? It will not solve your problem per se but will give the source of the problem such that a solution could be proposed :-)

Comment: Of course. When I execute I get No mapping found.

Comment: Add what is the output of `:verbose imap #`?

Comment: Hi. Appologies for the delay. I added the above to my init.vim but I still get errors. They are too long for the comment so I have added them to the question.

Comment: I assume for some reason the above command is not dissabling the options

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you verify that `let g:vimtex_imaps_disabled = ['b', 'B', 'c', 'f', '/', '-']` is in your `init.vim` command. Can you tell us what is the result of the `:echo g:vimtex_imaps_disabled` command?

Comment: Hi, yes I have double checked.  When I execute the echo command I get ['b', 'B', 'c', 'f', '/', '-'].

Comment: Do you have a recent version of vimtex?

Comment: Yes. I cloned it from github. I can provide video of me doing any ctions you think could help diagnose this.

Comment: I don't think the video would help. I'll propose you another solution :-)

Comment: Is the new solution working for you?

Comment: I am so blind, I didn't see that you updated your answer - I was waiting for a notifcation that you have posted another one. This worked! I am not sure what was going on here. Thank you very much

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)