# Can I delete an entire line, except the line break?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

A fairly common operation for me in Vim, since I am compulsive-obsessive and like to keep my files free of whitespace, is to delete the *contents* of an entire line, but not the line itself (i.e. not the line break).

Is there a built-in Vim way to do this? Perhaps a <kbd>d</kbd>`<movement command>` operation?

So far, the best I have is (on the line in question) <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd>. Is there a quicker way?

Comment: As an alternative to trimming whitespace manually, you could use a plugin such as [vim-better-whitespace](https://github.com/ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace), which highlights trailing whitespace, provides a command to remove it all at once, and can even do it automatically on save.

Comment: See also [What's the simplest way to strip trailing whitespace from all lines in a file?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/454/whats-the-simplest-way-to-strip-trailing-whitespace-from-all-lines-in-a-file).

Comment: Even without a plugin, you can globally delete trailing whitespace using search-and-replace, e.g. `:%s/\s*$//`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use `0D` this will go to the first character on the line and delete until the end of the line.  Note that you can use `^D` if you want to leave any preceding whitespace alone.  Also, these operations cannot be repeated by using `.`.  If you want an operation which can be repeated with the `.` command, refer to David Lord's answer.

Help topics:

- `:help 0`
- `:help D`
- `:help ^`

Comment: While this is direct, to the point, and (probably) the fewest keystrokes, it's not repeatable using the `.` command. For that reason, I think `cc<Esc>` or `S<Esc>` is more attractive if you care about repeating.

Comment: That is true.  However, you could record it as a macro and repeat that using `.`.

Comment: In general, macros cannot be repeated with `.`. They work as if those keystrokes were entered interactively, so individual commands are treated separately. Using `.` will repeat only the last command in the macro.

Comment: I tested it, and that's not how it works for me.  If the record the macro, then use it using `@{reg}`, you can repeat it with `.` afterwards.

Comment: You're just repeating the last command of the macro, which is `D`. After a `0D` operation, your cursor will be left in column 0. If your cursor is already on the beginning of the line (after you move to another one), it will look like the macro was properly repeated. Try moving the cursor forward in the line and typing `.` -- you'll see that it only repeats `D`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.

Answer (score 28):

`cc <Esc>` will do as you ask, but is more keystrokes than `0D`. If you want to put something into that line afterwards, `cc` may be best.

Comment: If you include the Shift  it's the same and possibly easier.

Comment: While this is not the "cleanest" solution, it has one advantage: it's exactly one action, and so it's repeatable with the `.` command. In contrast, `0D` (as suggested in the chosen answer) is two actions: the `0` motion and the `D` command.

Comment: @Trengot it probably is easier than `0D` for me since I have `jk` mapped to `<Esc>` in my vimrc, so my hands wouldn't even have to leave the home row.

Comment: See @Nobilis answer: `S` is documented as "Synonym for `cc`"

Answer (score 17):

`S` and then `Ctrl+C` or `Esc` seems to accomplish the exact same function.

It can then be repeated with `.` as it constitutes a single action.

Comment: I was just thinking of adding this as an answer and then saw yours

Comment: `S` is a synonym for `cc`.

Answer (score 7):

`0D` is probably what you want.  It will delete from the cursor to the end of the line while leaving the line (and any characters before the cursor) in place.

Comment: Altho this answer is almos one year old, it is worth noting that `0D` will delete **from the beginning of the line**, not from the cursor position

Answer (score 4):

I typically use `ddO`. `dd` to delete the current line, and `O` (that's a capital o) to add a new line.

This is also 3 keystrokes, but `dd` counts only as 1 and a half, and I find `O` easier to type than `$` .

It's different from the `0D` solution in that it does auto-indentation, for example with this code (where `!···` is a tab, and █ the cursor:

```
def asd():
!···if foo:
!···!···foo()█
!···!···foobar()
```

`0D` will leave you with:

```
def asd():
!···if foo:
█
!···!···foobar()
```

And `ddO` will leave you with:

```
def asd():
!···if foo:
!···!···█
!···!···foobar()
```

And if you press `<Esc>` immediately after this, Vim should remove the auto-indentation, so you have the same as with `0D`.

There is no 'correct' way, it will depend what exactly you'll want to do. I prefer `ddO` because it's more flexible, and because it's "in my fingers" :-)

Comment: `^D` will leave the whitespace alone.

Comment: Since `O` leaves you in insert mode, this is equivalent to `cc`, except without auto-indentation....unless your line was already auto-indented.

Comment: This will behave differently on the last line of the file.

Answer (score 1):

My preferred way to do this is: `A<C-u>`

This puts you into insert mode at the end of the line, and then deletes all characters behind the cursor (i.e. the entire line, *except* the newline). I like this more than other suggestions because it has been trained into my muscle memory—it is not more efficient, more practical, or really better in any way, but it is mine.

Comment: Remark: to be comparable to the other solution it should include a trailing `<Esc>` to come back to Normal mode.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt some of the other answers use `cc` or `C` with the explicit purpose of entering text right away. It compares with them. But your remark is valid, this will end in insert mode.

Comment: But the `S` and the `cc` explicitly `<Esc>` in their answer as far as I can tell. But feel free to keep your solution as such. It was just a comment to talk ;-)

Answer (score 0):

And to save that one precious key stroke you can use `0C` which will delete all the characters on the current line and put you into insert mode.