# Deleting In Vim and Then Pasting Without new Line

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Many times in vim I would like to delete a line completely, so I use dd. However, I then need to paste that line into some other position within a line, but this inserts a newline before pasting, therefore, making it very difficult for me to get the desired result.
For example,

```
while( pasteInHere )
{
    cin >> n; // Delete this line completely with dd
}
```

when I do this with the above code I get:

```
while( pasteInHere )
cin >> n; // Delete this line completely with dd
{
}
```

which is very far from the result I want...how can I suppress this newline behaviour, or use another method that does it very efficiently? I don't think d$ is good because I not  only have to go to beginning of line, but if I want to delete the empty line too I need to delete it in another register, I feel like there should be an easier way! Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I delete an entire line, except the line break?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/can-i-delete-an-entire-line-except-the-line-break)

Comment: it is not a duplicate, as I said I want a more efficient way then going to beginning of line, also I actually want to remove the complete line with the newline character....not just the contents of the line

Comment: Oh, I do see what you mean now.  It just wasn't very clear to me what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: `0D` delete line except line break. And than `gJ` to join lines. Now you can put the text without break line and no empty line.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can go anywhere in the line above the line you want to delete, then press `JD` and paste it with `p` at the desired point.

- `J` joins the two lines and moves you at the start of the text you wanted to delete. This deletes a new-line character and the indentation of the line you want to move.
- `D` deletes from the current cursor position to the end of the line but preserves the new-line character.

**Hint:** You can use `:pu` if you deleted with `D` or yanked with `y$` and you want to paste *with* a new line.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something that works quite well with an `imap`. Add the following to your `vimrc`:

```
inoremap <c-a> <c-r>1<esc>k$Jxi
```

This will create a mapping for <kbd>CTRL-a</kbd> that will paste the last deleted text (with `dd` or similar). If you prefer, you may of course use a different key for the mapping.

References:

```
:h i_CTRL-R
:h quote1
:h J
```

Answer (score 3):

Not really simpler, but slightly more efficient, and you can also create normal-mode maps for both sequence:

- yanking: go to the line you want to move, then
  <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>
- pasting: go to the word you want to replace, then
  <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

### Paste without new line

Put this in your .vimrc file:

```
" Paste yanked line without line breaks before/after cursor position
nnoremap gP i<CR><Esc>PkJxJx
nnoremap gp a<CR><Esc>PkJxJx
```

Example:

```
<span style="color:">danger</span>
```

Now you can type `gp` to insert `#D51B3F` after `color:` while my cursor is at `:` in Normal mode.

### Yank without new line

Use flukus' answer:

```
" Delete current line without yanking the line breaks
nnoremap dil ^d$
```

as acronym of *delete inner line*. This also gets rid of leading indentation.

Answer (score 2):

This comes up for me a bit too, never thought to optimize it before but this mapping works:

```
nmap dil ^d$
```

`dil` is "delete in line", similar to `diw`, `di"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the text you want to copy by pressing `v` and then take it into buffer by pressing `y` and then paste it anywhere by `p`. It don't inserts any new line.

Comment: True, but this still leaves a blank line.

Answer (score 0):

### Pasting deleted line, without new-line:

*Althought It took me quite a while, thankfully I evetually found out how (PS. i'm new to VIM)*

- For `VI\VIM` and `.vimrc`, use:

```
nnoremap dil dd:let @+=matchlist(strtrans(@+),'[ ]*\zs.*\ze\^@')[0]<CR>
```

- For `NVIM` and `init.lua` *(like me)*, use:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', 'dil', "dd:let @+=matchlist(strtrans(@+),'[ ]*\\zs.*\\ze\\^@')[0]<CR>")
```

### Demonstration

[image]

### Regex explained

- ***Regex `[ ]*\zs.*\ze\^@`***:
- - *`[ ]*\zs`* look *(behind)* for potential spaces
- - *`.*`* and then match anything, only if
- - *`\ze\^@`* at the end there is a `^@`

### References

- [Regex Look behind\front explained](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Regex_lookahead_and_lookbehind)
- ["Delete in line"](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3960/42370) *(I stole the word "dil" from there hehe)*
- [remove newlines from a register in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6228454/11465149) *(Where i got the idea from)*
- [Is there a function which can return a list of matching text for groups in a regex?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7029/42370)

Comment: This relies on `@+` which is a clipboard register and is only written by `dd` based on the `'clipboard'` settings. Instead, you might want to use `@"` or `v:register`