# Is there a function which can return a list of matching text for groups in a regex?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

Bash can natively match regular expressions in the `[[ ]]` construct, using the `=~` operator. When it matches something, the result is stored in the [`BASH_REMATCH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-BASH_005fREMATCH) array variable. `BASH_REMATCH` contains, in order, the entire matched text, and then each matched subexpression:

```
$ foo=abcd
$ [[ $foo =~ (.(.))(.) ]]
$ printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
abc
ab
b
c
```

Is there something that would look like:

```
let foo = 'abcd'
let bar = groupmatch(foo, '\(.\(.\)\)\(.\)')
```

And `echo bar` would give:

```
['abc', 'ab', 'b', 'c']
```

It would be something like `split()`, but far, *far* more powerful. The `(.(.))(.)` is just a toy expression - the full power of regular expressions can be availed in `[[ ]]`.

Comment: FYI:  `:h function-list` will list functions grouped by what they are used for

Comment: @PeterRincker thanks, it's easy to zone out in the main list at `:h functions`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you could try [`matchlist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#matchlist%28%29) and `filter()`, like this:

```
:let foo = 'abcd'
:let bar = filter(matchlist(foo, '\v(.(.))(.)'), 'v:val !=# ""')
```

The output of `:echo bar` should be:

```
['abc', 'ab', 'b', 'c']
```

`matchlist()` by itself always returns a list of ten items if the match was successful, one for each possible sub-expression, whether or not the pattern actually contained enough sub-expressions:

```
:echo matchlist('abcd', '\v(.(.))(.)')
['abc', 'ab', 'b', 'c', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

More than nine sub-expressions causes it to error out:

```
:echo matchlist('abcdefghijklmn', '\v(.(.))(.(.))(.(.))(.(.))(.(.))(.(.))')
E872: (NFA regexp) Too many '('
E51: Too many (
[]
```

Whereas Bash can go further:

```
$ foo=abcdefghijklmn
$ [[ $foo =~ (.(.))(.(.))(.(.))(.(.))(.(.))(.(.)) ]]
$ printf "%s\n" "${#BASH_REMATCH[@]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[@]}"
13
abcdefghijkl
ab
b
cd
d
ef
f
gh
h
ij
j
kl
l
```

Comment: Nice. I'd given up on the `match*()` functions as being related to `:match`.  So, if I read this correctly, as with regular expressions in Vim, this is limited to 9 groups, and the list returned always has 10 entries, no matter how many groups were actually used?

Comment: @muru I'm no expert, but I think so. At least in the help, they talk about `submatches, like "\1", "\2", etc. in :substitute`. And afaik, with `:substitute` you can only refer to 10 submatches.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct error. Just a typo when I re-ran the commands for copying here.