# Removing redundant whitespaces on save/write

Tags: whitespace

I want all redundant whitespaces to be removed on write/save. How can I do that?
By redundant I mean ones that exists after the last character or if there's an empty line and it contains a few whitespaces.

Answer (score 5):

Probably something like that should work:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//
```

The autocommand triggers `:%s/\s\+$//` each time a buffer will be written. And the substitution command removes all of the whitespaces at the end of lines.

Answer (score 3):

I have a function for this, which also saves the cursor position:

```
function! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
  " save last search & cursor position
  let _s=@/
  let l = line(".")
  let c = col(".")
  %s/\s\+$//e
  let @/=_s
  call cursor(l, c)
endfunction
```

This function can be called on the writepre hook:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.rb,*.php,*.py,*.js,*.txt,*.hs,*.java,*.md call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

Or if you want it on every file:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
```

Note: I have not written this function, but copied it from somewhere. Unfortunaly i don't remember where i found it. As pointed out in the comments, the source is probably vimcast ([link](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/)). So even if it doesn't matter for you, i don't want to take credit for this function, and vimcast can't be mentioned enough, as it is a great source for vim related knowledge.

Comment: Your source is (probably) [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tidying-whitespace/)

Comment: @statox i think the source of my source was vimecast ^^. But thanks a lot for the link, i added it to my answer.

Comment: See [@Carpetsmoker's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/456/343) to a related question for a much simpler version of the function.

Comment: @Rich interesting, thank you a lot. It even saves fold and some more stuff, guess i have to adept my preserve function =)