# How do I remove newlines inside arbitrary xml tags matching a pattern?

Tags: regular-expression, multiple-lines, filetype-xml, join

I'm working with large xml files that have tags, and some are spread across multiple lines, and some are on a single line. I'd like them to all be on a single line. There are other tags in the files besides the one I want to modify.

```
<group value="abc">
   <line value="abc" value2="def"/>
   <line value="ghi"
      value2="jkl"/>
</group>
```

I would like it to look like:

```
<group value="abc">
   <line value="abc" value2="def"/>
   <line value="ghi" value2="jkl"/>
</group>
```

I've tried two approaches so far. The first is to try to apply a join to a range for the `<line>` tag. The second is to try to do a substitution across multiple lines to remove newlines and extra whitespace. Some examples that almost work.

```
:g/<line/,/\/>/join
:v/\/>/g/<line/,/\/>/join
:g/<line\_.{-}\/>/s/\n\s*/ /g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I never knew that you can have a search in the range. Thanks for making me learn something new!

Second off, you were really close with `:g/<line/,/\/>/join`. But I'm pretty sure that the problem is that the second line i.e.

```
  <line value="abc" value2="def"/>
```

Is also matched by `<line/,/\/>` so this line is joined with the next when it shouldn't be. I guess the search can't match it's own line. This seems to be consistent behavior. For example, try putting this into your buffer:

```
abc
abc
```

And doing

```
:,/abc/join
```

This does join the two lines together. So to get around this, we'll need to make sure that closed tags are not matched. Originally I had:

```
:g/<line.*\(\/>\)\@!..$/,/\/>/j
```

This will match any line containing `<line` that doesn't end with `/>`.

If this seems like black magic, try mentally breaking it up into 3 parts:

```
<line.*
\(\/>\)\@!
..$
```

And read up on the [`:h /\@!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21) quantifier.

But now as I write up this answer, I realized there's a much simpler solution using negative character ranges:

```
:g/<line.*[^/][^>]$/,/\/>/j
```

This is both simpler, and *waaaaay* easier to understand.

Comment: This worked! But only after I removed the trailing whitespace on some lines via `:%s/\s\+$//e`. [https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/454/whats-the-simplest-way-to-strip-trailing-whitespace-from-all-lines-in-a-file using]

Comment: And yes, the search within a range is powerful. There's some interesting stuff you can do with it, for instance one trick is to search for something at the end of a block, then you can create a backwards range from it as per: `g/regex1/?regex2?+1;/regex3/-1d`